# Switching GPUs with 'sudo prime-select intel' causes Vulkan error, leading to slow startup and lag in Chromium apps

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, chromium, vulkan

I'm encountering an issue when switching from the Nvidia GPU to the integrated Intel GPU using `$ sudo prime-select intel` on my Linux system.

Specifically, I'm experiencing a `'Couldn't get vkCreateInstance via vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr for ICD libGLX_nvidia.so.0 Cannot create Vulkan instance'` error message. This problem is leading to slow application startup and laggy performance, and it seems to be primarily affecting Chromium-based applications such as Chrome and VSCode. I've updated my Nvidia drivers and checked for Vulkan support on both GPUs, but the issue persists. Any suggestions or solutions to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on wayland.
[My laptop specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUsUm.png)
[Nvidia driver version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5sUs.png)

Additional logs:

```
google-chrome.desktop[8008]: Warning: loader_scanned_icd_add: Could not get 'vkCreateInstance' via 'vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr' for ICD libGLX_nvidia.so.0
Oct 29 17:54:28 m-XPS-15-9510 google-chrome.desktop[8008]: ../../third_party/libc++/src/include/string:914: assertion __s != nullptr failed: basic_string(const char*) detected nullptr
Oct 29 17:54:28 m-XPS-15-9510 google-chrome.desktop[8008]: [8705:1:1029/175428.119420:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(319)] GPU state invalid after WaitForGetOffsetInRange.
Oct 29 17:54:28 m-XPS-15-9510 google-chrome.desktop[8008]: [8731:1:1029/175428.119559:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(127)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
Oct 29 17:54:28 m-XPS-15-9510 google-chrome.desktop[8008]: [8002:8002:1029/175428.120795:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=134
Oct 29 17:54:37 m-XPS-15-9510 wpa_supplicant[1047]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-61 noise=9999 txrate=520000
```